How to execute a python script on Mac with Shortcuts/Automator
I am trying to find out if it is possible to execute a Python script I made with one click/Shortcuts.
I.e. I don't wish to open the terminal or VS code to execute it, but "just run it" as it is.
Is that possible?
Best,
Anders
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import locale
import smtplib
import ssl

stocks_dict = {
    "YOU": 'About You Holding SE',
    "CSIQ": 'Canadian Solar'
}

def format_currency(value):
    return '{:.2f}'.format(value).replace('.', ',')

def get_stock_data(ticker, name):
    stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    end_date = datetime.now()
    start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=2)
    history = stock.history(start=start_date, end=end_date)
    current_price = stock.history(period='1d')['Close'].iloc[-1]
    current_price = round(current_price, 2)
    if len(stock.history(period='2d')) >= 2:
        previous_close = stock.history(period='2d')['Close'].iloc[-2]
        price_change_percent = ((current_price - previous_close) / previous_close) * 100
    else:
        price_change_percent = float('nan')
    highest_price_last_year = stock.history(period='1y')['Close'].max()
    highest_price_last_year  = round(highest_price_last_year, 2)
    highest_price_last_5_years = stock.history(period='5y')['Close'].max()
    highest_price_last_5_years = round(highest_price_last_5_years,2)

    return (f"{name} ({ticker})\n"
            f"Kursudvikling de sidste 24 timer: {'N/A' if price_change_percent is None else f'{round(price_change_percent, 2)}%'}\n"
            f"Nuværende kurs: {format_currency(current_price)} USD\n"
            f"Højeste kurs sidste år: {format_currency(highest_price_last_year)} USD\n"
            f"Højeste kurs sidste 5 år: {format_currency(highest_price_last_5_years)} USD\n\n")

def send_mail(subject, body, sender_email, recipient_email, password):
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    smtp_server = "smtp.simply.com"
    smtp_port = 587

    email_message = f"From: {sender_email}\n"
    email_message += f"To: {recipient_email}\n"
    email_message += f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"
    email_message = email_message.encode("utf-8")

    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
            server.starttls(context=context)
            server.login(sender_email, password)
            server.sendmail(sender_email, recipient_email, email_message)
            print(f"E-mail sendt til {recipient_email}!")
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print(f"Fejl i send_mail: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Generel fejl i send_mail: {e}")

sender_email = "..."
recipient_email = "..."
password = "..."

email_subject = "Stock Data Overview"
email_body = ""

for ticker, name in stocks_dict.items():
    email_body += get_stock_data(ticker, name)

send_mail(email_subject, email_body, sender_email, recipient_email, password)


I have tried looking into Shortscuts and Automator. Automator "worked" but it didn't allow "import yfinance as yf" and threw an error.

Both Shortcuts and Automator have "run shell script" (or something like that — I have my Mac set to Swedish where it’s "Kör kommandotolkskript") actions that look promising. What error did you get, exactly?

See error on https://share.cleanshot.com/HY5ytD0N

It might be an environment issue. I have not installed yfinance and I get the same error message, about not being able to find the module. By default, the environment in automator/applescript is different than that which the terminal uses so your standard path will not be available unless you add it within the script.
